# d3.path plots only first feature of feature collection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot a map of the UK and plotting a few selected points on it. 
I am following the first part of this tutorial https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

Here's what I have done.

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
.attr('height', height)
.attr('width', width)
.call(zoom);

d3.json("/data/uk.json", function(error, uk) {

   if (error) return console.error(error);

  var subunits = topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits);
  var projection = d3.geo.albers()
                 .center([0, 55.4])
                 .rotate([4.4, 0])
                 .parallels([50, 60])
                 .scale(6000)
                 .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
          .projection(projection);
svg.append('path')
         .datum(subunits)
         .attr('d', path);

svg.selectAll('.subunit')
    .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits).features)
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr('d', path);
```

Here is the part where I try to plot the points

```
d3.json('/data/places.json',  function (error , result) {

    if(error)
      console.error(error);

    svg.append('path')
              .data(result.features)
              .style('stroke', 'green')
              .attr('d' , d3.geo.path().projection(projection))
  });
```

The above code plots only one point on the map, i.e the first one in the JSON file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correctly binding your features' data when using

```
svg.append('path')
   .data(result.features)
   .style('stroke', 'green')
   .attr('d' , d3.geo.path().projection(projection))
```

This will append one path, bind the first element of `result.features` to this path and set the style and attribute accordingly.

To work the way you want it, you need to make use of the [data joining](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#joining-data) mechanism of D3.

```
svg.selectAll('path.features')
   .data(result.features)
  .enter().append('path')
    .attr('class', 'feature')
    .style('stroke', 'green')
    .attr('d' , d3.geo.path().projection(projection))
```

This will compute a [data join](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) for the features in `result.features` putting the new elements in the enter selection which is accessible by calling [`enter()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_enter) on the seletion. Using this enter selection you can now append paths for all your features.

---

A further side note not directly related to your issue:
Depending on the number of features you want to append to your map, the `.attr("d")` setter might be called quite often. You could improve performance by reusing one instance of the path generator:

```
var geoPath = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);  // You need just one instance

svg.selectAll('path.features')
   .data(result.features)
  .enter().append('path')
    .attr('class', 'feature')
    .style('stroke', 'green')
    .attr('d' , geoPath)                             // Re-use the path generator
```

This is considered best practice, which should be generally applied.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Could You please tell me what is going on here? I thought `d3.geo.path()` had to be passed the data element for which it has to make a path.  And why do we explicitly mention the projection?

Comment: Calling `d3.geo.path()` will yield a *path generator* which computes screen coordinates of SVG elements based on GeoJSON geomety features. For this to work you obviously have to pass in both the projection as well as the data containing the GeoJSON feature. While the former is done by calling `.projection()'  on the path generator, the latter will be taken care of by the internal magic of D3's data binding. To understand how data binding works, start reading into the links I included in my answer.

Comment: @AdityaRamani Another tip: Consider reusing the path generator which will improve performance. I have updated my answer to cover this.